# Error when building WP8.1 Apps on Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I've recently installed new Visual Studio 2015 community in my pc. So whenver I'm trying to build my WP8.1 project, I get this following error.

[image]

How can I fix this? Please help me with relevant solutions. Thank you!

EDIT:

I've tried repairing. Then I faced this problem. No matter how many times I try to repair, I'm getting this problem.

[image]

Comment: Does that target exist? Is it a reference in your project that you're expecting to be present, or is it the output from your build?

Comment: Target does not exist. And the project I'm trying to build is an empty one, so there's no need for a reference.

Comment: Try to repair Visual Studio (from the control panel, edit > repair)

Comment: Ok, I've repaired just now but the problem still persists! @cFrozenDeath

Comment: 1 screen shot and 1 photograph of your screen?

Comment: I've already added in my question! @Mathemats